# Trying to display an array using a *ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops

I grouped a data array using lodash and can see the output in my console, but my `*ngFor` loops don't display the data on my html page. Can anyone point out what I'm missing here?

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  data = [
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-04-18"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Dick"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-06-30"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Harry"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-04-03"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-05-03"
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Sort by Month

    // Format month
    const monthName = item =>
      moment(item.transaction_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM");

// Establish groupBy array
    const byMonth = _.chain(this.data)
      .groupBy(monthName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();
    console.log(byMonth);
    return byMonth;
    console.log(monthName);

    // By Day
    const dayName = item =>
      moment(item.transaction_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD");

    const byDay = _.chain(this.data)
      .groupBy(dayName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();
    console.log(byDay);
    return byDay;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<table *ngFor="let month of months">
    <tr>
        <th>{{month.month}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table *ngFor="let customer of customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{customer.name}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Desired HTML Format (in a table but the formatting wasn't supported):**

- April

  - John
  - Harry
- May

  - Dick
- June

  - John

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: You're not defining `customers` in your component controller, and the correct syntax is `*ngFor="let customer of customers"`. I imagine you have some errors in the console.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it looks like the only fields existing outside of ngOnInit() are name and data.  So I don't think you'd be able to iterate over months or customers with an *ngFor.

Comment: i fixed the ngfor loop but it's still not displaying the table

Comment: if the 'data' equals to your 'customers'? looking at the format, your name is inside customer object, when loop, it should be like let customer of customers.... {{ customer.customer.name }}, and for the date, {{ customer.transaction_date }}

Comment: OKay, ive remade my problem here, could you take a look?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkpyvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes, but you're close.

1) You need to declare a public property in your component that will be used to loop through. Notice how I created `public myData`.

2) You then need to initialize that object with the data you want to display. In your original code you were trying to do a `return` from the `ngOnInit`. That is not what you want to do. You want to assign that data to your public property `myData`

3) You have to recognize Angular **`ngFor` does not want to loop through anything that is not an array by default**. Lucky for you since Angular version 6 they provided support to loop over objects. However, in order to accomplish that you need to include the new pipe `| keyvalue`.

Working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adkojd)

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";

  public myData = {};

  data = [
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-04-18"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Dick"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-06-30"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "Harry"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-04-03"
    },
    {
      customer: {
        name: "John"
      },
      transaction_date: "2017-05-03"
    }
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Sort by Month

    // Format month
    const monthName = item =>
      moment(item.transaction_date, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM");

    // Establish groupBy array
    this.myData = _.chain(this.data)
      .groupBy(monthName)
      .mapValues(items => _.map(items, "customer.name"))
      .value();
    console.log(this.myData);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table *ngFor="let data of myData | keyvalue">
    <tr>
        <th>{{data.key}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table *ngFor="let customer of data.value">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{customer}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! It looks like my main issue was I never declared the public property. I'm very new to Angular so I still have quite a bit to learn, thank you again! :D